# Why are nested anonymous pure functions shielded from evaluation?

Tags: evaluation, pure-function

I tried the following code (ignoring the warning messages):

```
{#, # &, Function[{x}, #], Function[{#}, x], Function[{#}, #]} &@7
(*result: {7, #1 &, Function[{x}, 7], Function[{7}, x], Function[{7}, 7]}*)
```

I wonder why `#&` was not changed into `7&`.
I saw a "possible issue" similar to this mentioned in ref/Slot, but I couldn't find further documentation about it. Is it a bug or it is specially designed this way?

Comment: `# &` creates a pure function as the second element of the list. Then after the end of the list `}` you create another pure function and the slots of *that* function are then filled with `7`.

Comment: I think the following set is a bit more illustrative: `{Function[#] &[7], Function[Null, #] &[7], Function[x, #] &[7], With[{t = #}, Function[t]] &[7]}`